# Problem with copying 2 columns of a text file in to another text file using loop

Tags: awk

I have a text file called `file2.txt` with 19 columns of data. I would like to copy 2 columns at a time for example C2 & C3, C2 & C4, C2 & C5, ..., C2 & C19 into 17 different text files. I need column C2 in every text file as common data, I am trying to do it using a for loop:

```
awk 'BEGIN { for (i = 2; i <= 19; i++) -v i="$i" '{print $2 $i}'file2.txt > filei.txt}'
```

But I get these errors:

```
awk: BEGIN { for (i = 3; i <= 18; i++) -v i="$i" {print
awk:                                       ^ syntax error
awk: Commnadline:1: BEGIN { for (i = 3; i <= 18; i++) -v i="$i" {print
awk:  unexpected newline or end of string
```

Can you help out?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
awk '{for (i=2;i<=NF;i++) print $1,$i > "file" i ".txt"}' file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Tested and worked fine

```
file data

c1 c2 c3 c4 c5 c6 c7 c8 c9 c10 c11 c12 c13 c14 c15 c16 c17 c18 c19

co=`awk '{print $2}' filename `

no_of_colums=`awk '{print NF}' filename`

for ((i=3;i<=$no_of_colums;i++)); do awk -v i="$i" -v co="$co" '{print co,$i}' filename>$co"c"$i ; done
```